# Jenkins Pipeline: Poll SCM: Is there a way how to run it with parameters?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I would like to run Job every night at specific hour, but only if there are a new changes in repository.

Currently I am using **Build periodically with parameters** with this schedule:

```
 H(35-55) 1 * * * %GERRIT_REFSPEC=master;PUBLISH_APT=true
```

I tried to set it for Poll SCM, but I do not know, how to set parameters for that job. Is that possible?

Thanks

Jitka

Comment: You could set default parameters in the job if your params are always the same?

Comment: Unfortunatelly, these params are not always the same. It depends on trigger. I need to set up it to the trigger

Comment: How would the params change? Is there some algorithm or logic which determines the params? If so, you could set up a different job to run at this time, execute the logic, then trigger this job as a downstream job with the params you want.

Comment: Sorry, I should write more detail about the situation. I have a job and two triggers for it. Gerrit event and Build periodically with parameters. I would like to switch the Build perodidically with parameters to Poll SCM, but I have the parameters in Build with parameters, so I am not sure how to switch these trigger. Parameters for build differs if the build is trigger by gerrit event or periodically. Is that clear?